# How can I attach sock_ops bpf prog to cgroup v1?

Tags: ebpf, cgroups

For cgroup v2, I can attach sock_ops to unified cgroup via following command

```bash
bpftool cgroup attach "/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/" sock_ops pinned "/sys/fs/bpf/bpf_sockops"
```

Is it possible that sock_ops is attached to cgroup v1? How can I attach sock_ops to cgroup v1?